# On an equivalent condition of Cohen-Macaulay ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $ A $ be a finitely generated graded commutative $ k $-algebra. The ring $ A $ is said to be Cohen-Macaulay if it is Cohen-Macaulay as a module over itself.

Want to show:  This is equivalent to the condition that there is a polynomial subring  $ k[\xi_1,\cdots, \xi_r ]  \subseteq A $ generated by homogeneous elements $ \xi_i $, such that A is a finitely generated free module over $ k[\xi_1,\cdots, \xi_r ] $.

Following is What I have tried

Since $ A $ is Cohen-Macaulay, it depth $ A $=dimension $ A $, which let's say $ r $.

Let $  \xi_1,\cdots, \xi_r\in A$ be a regular sequence.  So we can form $  k[\xi_1,\cdots, \xi_r ] \subseteq A $ (maybe I am wrong here). Let $ R=  k[\xi_1,\cdots, \xi_r ]  $, which has depth=dimension= $ r $. We may think $ A $ as an $ R $-module.
By
Auslander–Buchsbaum formula

finite projective dimension of $A$+ depth of $ A $= depth of $ R $.

Hence projective dimension of $ A $ is zero, so $ A $ is projective. So $ A $ is free by the Quillen–Suslin theorem which states that every finitely generated projective module over a polynomial ring is free.

Question 1: Why $ A $ should have a finite projective dimension?

Question 2: Will this hold in case $ A $ is not finitely generated?

Comment: Note that in Auslander-Buchsbaum the base ring (here, $R$) must be *local*, and the depth is *as a $R$-module* (and relative to the maximal ideal of $R$).

Comment: For the first question, all finitely generated modules over a polynomial ring ( over a field, in finitely many variables) have finite projective dimension, since the ring is regular.

Comment: In my case, R is not local. Could you please let me know how to prove in this case?